# I want to compress the output for speed up loading of website in browser.

Tags: php, .htaccess, gzip, zlib, mod-deflate

I have tried mod_deflate enabling but failed in it. I have tried every code given in stackoverflow but still it is not loaded in modules. Then i tries enabling zlib. In phpinfo() it is showing enabled but output compression is off. I have tried in .htaccess

```
php_flag zlib.output_compression on
```

and in php.ini

```
zlib.output_compression = on
```

Then also it is showing like follows in phpinfo()

[phpinfo() zlib info snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvlnc.jpg)
 Can anyone help me to compress the output?

Comment: Have you verified you are editing the correct `php.ini`. Look at output of `phpinfo()` and search for `php.ini` to see which ini file is really used.

Comment: The php.ini path is Configuration File (php.ini) Path =/usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File =/usr/local/lib/php.ini . But there is no such directory exist so i create it in root folder. But still it has no success